# Подскажите по логике работы триггера

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Вопрос теоретический, сделал я триггер, который следит за изменением в таблице, и изменения эти записывает в результирующую таблицу. Следит триггер за операцией insert и update. В моем приложении в пустую таблицу из другого источника я записываю данные, через ado.net, когда данные попадают в таблицу, триггер в неактивном состоянии, иначе все данные, которые попали в основную таблицу оказываются в результирующей. Далее, когда процесс заполнения данными окончен, я включаю триггер программно, и все равно триггер берет все данные и переносит их в таблицу результата, хотя логика подразумевается такая, что я триггером беру только измененные данные в таблице с данными. Как понять почему так происходит и это справить.

Comment: А Вы транзакцию зафиксировали перед тем, как включить триггер?

Comment: @Akina нет , я даже не представлю механизм как это сделать, как сделать триггер повесть его на таблицу и заставить данные писать в нужное мне место это не вопрос,а про транзакции не думал даже.

Comment: Триггер - штука тупая. Пошло изменение - он заработал. У Вас сейчас логика получается такая: триггер выключен, данные типа добавлены, триггер включаем, соединение закрывается, транзакция фиксируется, данные записываются в таблицу, на что срабатывает триггер. Попробуйте после добавления данных явно выполнить COMMIT, и только потом ENABLE TRIGGER.

Comment: @Akina Да я походу этот момент совсем выпустил из вида, но активным триггер я делаю в коде программы, тоже не знаю верно ли это. Можно ли пример где то увидеть подобного?

Comment: Надо придумать какой нибудь другой подход, без изменения состояния триггера. Включение/выключение триггеров - это глобальное действие. Триггер не может в одной активной транзакции сейчас быть включенным, а в другом выключенным. Любое действие с ним возьмет полный блок на таблицу и остановит другие транзакции. Потенциально возможны deadlock. Иногда лучше как то пометить в самих изменяемых данных должен на них реагировать триггер или нет

Comment: @Mike а как тогда следить за изменением, по логике мне нужно чтобы я знал какая запись в таблице изменилась, чтобы далее только ее взять и обработать.Триггер это позволяет сделать. Но я не могу настроить его работу так как мне нужно

Comment: измененные записи "до" и "после" в триггере доступны в "таблицах" inserted и delited

Comment: @Mike мой триггер настроен на после вставки, с начало в таблицу заливаются данные, затем триггер смотрит, какие данные в процессе работы изменились,А в данном случае сейчас, то что залилось, то и отобразилось как измененное.

Comment: под "до" и "после" я имел ввиду что в deleted видно как выглядели данные до изменения, а в inserted новая версия. К тому как работает триггер before/after это не имеет отношения. В обоих видах триггеров содержимое этих "таблиц" будет одинаково (с поправкой на изменения, которые может внести триггер before) https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-2017